# Why is Jesus sitting at "God’s right hand" not "the Father's right hand"?

Tags: jesus, trinity

When I do the search

https://www.openbible.info/topics/jesus_sitting_at_the_right_hand_of_the_father

I actually do not get phrases in which Jesus is sitting at the right hand of the father, but instead the right hand side of God, or the power of God and similar, e.g. Acts 7, 56.

How does this coincide with the doctrine of the trinity? According to the doctrine of the trinity I understand that Jesus and the Father are personas of God. While I cannot claim to understand what that means, I would intuitively expected that Jesus should be sitting next to the Father.

https://www.gotquestions.org/right-hand-God.html mentions that

> Therefore, what we can say is that "God’s right hand" refers to the Messiah, the LORD Jesus Christ and He is of equal position, honor, power and authority with God (John 1:1-5).

Also here I would have expected to see "Father" instead of "God".

On the other hand it seems that Jesus "went" to the father

> And Jesus, crying out with a loud voice, said, "Father, into your hands I commit my spirit." Having said this, He breathed His last. (Luke 23:46)

and by with the Father

> For just as the Father has life in Himself, even so He gave to the Son also to have life in Himself. (John 5:26)

Is "God’s right hand" a title / expression but not to be understood as a description of the relationship of God/Jesus/Father?

(This questions was inspired by [Why does Jesus commit his spirit into his Father's hands at death?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/47522), but is different.)

Comment: This question may be judged off-topic for this site due it the fact that it states a topic for debate and does not examine a particular text. Please see the Tour and the Help (below, bottom right) as to the purpose and functioning of the site.

Comment: @steveowen You can't make such massive substantial changes to someone else's question without their permission. Ask your own question if you're interested in this verse.

Comment: @curious the Q is mostly 'answer' without focus on one verse. What else could be done to 'save' it?  So many times it's said to, "just ask the Q"! It won't reopen as it is will it?

Comment: @steveowen No, I don't think anything can be done to 'save' this question. But it doesn't need to be. It's not going anywhere. It won't be autodeleted because it has upvoted answers. Nothing needs to be done, it can just be left alone forever.

Comment: have you ever asked yourself if there is a left-hand side of God?

Comment: @Constantthin: Sure, but I am not aware, that it is mentioned. I suspected that "right-hand side" is mostly figuratively and the point is not to discuss literal "hands" of God. However, the question regarding persons remains relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Jesus sits at the right hand of God because the throne is God's.

The Book of Revelation clearly distinguishes between the Almighty God, “Him who sits on the throne” (Revelation 4) and “the Lamb standing, as though it had been slain” (Revelation 5). The two are never confused. The Lamb is not God (who sits on the throne), God is not the Lamb. The God of chapter 4 is worshiped because He is God who created everything.

We can all agree that “the Lamb, standing as though it had been slain” in the Book of Revelation 5:6 is Jesus the Messiah, who was killed, but then raised from the dead. God, on the other hand, does not die, and is not raised from the dead.

Note how the Lamb is continually differentiated from God, who sits on the throne. That is, God is not the Lamb, and the Lamb is not God:

“To Him who sits on the throne and to the Lamb be blessing and honor and glory and might forever and ever!”.– Rev. 5:13

"Fall on us and hide us from the face of Him who is seated on the throne, and from the wrath of the Lamb”.Rev. 6:16

After this I looked, and behold, a great multitude that no one could number…standing before the throne and before the Lamb, clothed in white robes, with palm branches in their hands.– Rev. 7:
“…crying out with a loud voice, “Salvation belongs to our God who sits on the throne, and to the Lamb!”– Rev. 7:10

The same distinction between God, on the one hand, and the Lamb on the other, is made in Revelation 7:17, 14:4, 15:3, 21:22, 21:23, 22:1 and 22:3. In many other places in the Book of Revelation, Jesus Christ and the symbols representing Jesus Christ are differentiated from God (e.g., Rev. 11:15, 12:5).

The last two references to God and the Lamb in the Book of Revelation (Rev. 22:1 and 22:3) contain the phrase “the throne of God and of the Lamb”. Some Trinitarians claim that this phrase shows that the Lamb is God. But this assumption is wrong for several reasons:

In these verses as well, God is distinguished from the Lamb. Whoever God is, He is not the Lamb. The Lamb is not God, and God is not the Lamb. The Lamb was slain and raised. God is not slain and raised.
This incorrect interpretation ignores all the other references in the Book of Revelation which also differentiate between God and the Lamb, and which state that the Lamb has a God.
The Lamb shares the throne of God because God has granted this to the Lamb: “he shall rule…even as I myself have received power from my Father (Rev. 2:27, 3:21, cf. Matt. 28:18). **As a parallel, the LORD God put both David and Solomon on His (God’s) throne. “Then Solomon sat on the throne of the LORD as king in place of David his father” (1 Chron. 29:23). But neither David nor Solomon were God just because they were granted by God to rule as God’s representatives on God’s throne. As God’s chosen, anointed kings, David and Solomon were granted to sit on God’s throne. So is the risen Jesus Christ.**
It is clear from the Book of Revelation that Jesus Christ, the Lamb who was slain but who now lives, the firstborn from the dead, the beginning of God’s creation, is not God.

Sometimes Trinitarians say that the deity of Christ was revealed to the apostles gradually or progressively. If that were the case, we should expect to find Jesus clearly presented as God in the Book of Revelation, the last book of the New Testament canon. Yet that is not the case. Instead, the Book of Revelation distinguishes between God and Jesus. Revelation tells us that God is not Jesus and Jesus is not God.

It is apparent throughout the NT that Christ, before and after his resurrection, is shown to be distinct from God the Father. John 5:44 (only means **monou, Strong's Greek 3441: Only, solitary, desolate.** God") Jesus' language here is explicit as it is elsewhere. In John 17:3 ASV (And this is life eternal, that they should know **thee the only true God,** and **him whom thou didst send, even Jesus Christ**) two persons are distinguished, one inferior to the other. "Throughout Paul's epistles ...this distinction is carefully observed, (1 Timothy 2:5 ASV For there is one God, one mediator also between God and men, himself man, Christ Jesus) in which one being alone is always called God (Adonai), the other, without exception, lord (Adoni) ...Again, Christ is expressly declared to be inferior and subordinate to God the Father. He himself said: "**My Father ...is greater than all**" (John 10:29) and yet more precisely, "**My Father is greater than I** (John 14:28). He is said to be "chosen," "appointed," "inspired," "sanctified," by God; "anointed," "given," Matthew 12:18; Luke 4:18; John 3:34 and thirty-five times in St. John's Gospel alone, "sent" by God. It is recorded that he came to do his Father's will—came in the name of the Lord. John 4:34; 12:49; 6:38; Matthew 21:9.  In St. Matthew's Gospel he is called the "servant of God." Matthew 12:18. **Surely, the being that is chosen, appointed, sent, inspired, sanctified, who comes in the name of the Lord, and is God's servant, etc., cannot be said to be equal to his master.**

Even after his exaltation, Matthew 28:18  to the right hand of God, Acts 5:31, he is still subordinate. He now reigns in the heavenlies, but soon he will return on the clouds in power and glory to establish God's Kingdom on this earth for a thousand years. After the thousand years he will still be seen to be subordinate to God the father and be subject to Him, **1 Corinthians 15:27-28** for he will return the kingdom to the Father. "Then comes the end, when he delivers the kingdom to God the Father after destroying every rule and every authority and power. For he must reign until he has put all his enemies under his feet. The last enemy to be destroyed is death. For 'God has put all things in subjection under his feet.' But when it says, 'all things are put in subjection,' it is plain that he is excepted who put all things in subjection under him. When all things are subjected to him, **then the Son himself will also be subjected to him who put all things in subjection under him, that God may be all in all"** (ESV).

Your question "How does this coincide with the doctrine of the trinity?"

"...the Trinity is 'an unintelligible proposition of Platonic mysticisms that three are one and one is three; and yet one is not three and three are not one."

"There is no passage of Scripture which asserts that God is three. No authentic verse claims that the One God is three persons, three spirits, three divine, infinite minds, or three anything. No verse or word of the Bible can be shown to carry the meaning 'God in three Persons.' Any claim that there are three who compose the deity must be based on inference, rather than plain statements.

If some believe that Jesus is God, why wouldn't they believe him when he said that the Father is the only true God, John 17:3; 5:44 that the Father is greater than him, John 14:28. Jesus has a God, John 20:17. **Jesus ascribed creation to God, not himself, Mark 10:6 YLT (but from the beginning of the creation, a male and a female God did make them)** In Jesus' plain and unequivocal statements, he is not the only true God and Creator. His God is.

Comment: Well said indeed Alex. The only thing I would add is with regard to Mark 10:6, because the Trinitarians might make something of it otherwise. Jesus did indeed "ascribe" creation to the Almighty. In that the Almighty was the "Architect" of creation, with Jesus as his "Contractor". See Proverbs 8:1-36, where "Wisdom" is personified, but whether it's "So.phia" (Greek), or "Chokh.mah/Cha.kham" (Hebrew), where skill in "Crafting" is implied, one can't fail to associate with the Word of God, who would become Jesus, especially when considering 8:30, as how can wisdom "truly" be a master workman...

Comment: ....and I was proud to be the 3rd person to vote you up. What "Wisdom" you showed in crafting that answer....

Comment: So how do you interpret John 1:1, Hebrews 1:8, and other passages?

Comment: @JamesAjiduah. Please post it as a question and I will answer it.

Comment: I'm realising more and more that the author of Revelation teaches through unexpected 'twists' in the plot. The twist in this scene (Rev 4-5), is that, yes, while God on the throne is worshipped at the beginning of the scene (Rev 4: 8-11), by its end (end ch. 5), the Lamb is worshipped with a declamation that is extremely similar to the refrain used to worship God on the throne (Rev. 5:12 cf. Rev. 4:11a). Both God AND the Lamb are worshipped equally by the end of the 'worship liturgy' (Rev. 5:13b).

Comment: I'm kinda stunned that for as non trinitarian as this post is it has received zero down votes. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

There is consistent support for Jesus sitting or standing next to God.

> Psalm 110:1 The LORD said unto my Lord, Sit thou at my right hand, until I make thine enemies thy footstool. (this is a prophesy)

> But he (Stephen), full of the holy spirit, gazed into heaven and saw the glory of God, and Jesus standing at the right hand of God. Acts 7:55, 6

> Luke 22:69 But from now on the Son of Man will be seated at the right hand of the power of God."

> He sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high Heb 1:3

Mark 14:62, Acts 2:33, Col 3:1, Rom 8:34, Heb 10:12, 1 Peter 3:22

**He is never spoken of as being next to the Father.**

If Jesus is next to God, then he cannot BE God. Some like to dance around this clear fact to make another reality about God sitting next to God or something that the text does not intend by the exclusive use of *God* as the reference.

Before Jesus arrives at his ultimate destination by God's side, he has clearly been provided with everything he needed - authority as Lord and Christ.

> Jesus came to them and said, “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to me. Matt 28:18

> having been exalted at the right hand of God, and having received the promise of the Holy Spirit from the Father  Acts 2:33

> let all the house of Israel know for certain that God has made him both Lord and Christ Acts 2:36

> So also Christ did not glorify himself to become a high priest, but the One having said to him: "You are My Son, today I have begotten you." Heb 5:5

This is the ultimate fulfilment of the type that Joseph lived out in Egypt.

> So Pharaoh said to Joseph,... “You shall be in charge of my house, and all my people shall be obedient to you; only regarding the throne will I be greater than you.”...  “See, I have placed you over all the land of Egypt.” 42Then Pharaoh took off his signet ring from his hand and put it on Joseph’s hand, and clothed him in garments of fine linen, and put the gold necklace around his neck. 43And he had him ride in his second chariot; and they proclaimed ahead of him, “Bow the knee!” And he placed him over all the land of Egypt Gen 41:39-

Notice the striking similarities to Jesus and his God exalting him;

- Joseph didn't *take* this position.
- He is over all *except* Pharaoh.
- He is given all authority *under* Pharaoh.
- His authority is over the whole land.
- Joseph had Pharaoh's ring of authority to make all decisions and judgements.
- Joseph is AS Pharaoh by wearing and using his ring.
- all *glory* too is given to Joseph
- Joseph has Pharaoh's (second) chariot - we are seeing Pharaoh from a distance, but no, it's really Joseph.
- we can hear the echo of, "let all God's angels worship him", with the people told to honour Joseph's presence - to 'bow the knee'.

Jesus is attested as a man by every NT text on this matter, including Jesus' own words.

> John 8:40 a **man** who has told you the truth that I heard from God.

He never says he is God or 'God the Son'. He has a God - the same (creator) God as all humans. John 5:44 the one and only God. 2 Cor 1:3, Eph 1:3, Col 1:3, 2 Cor 11:31, Rom 15:6, Rom 1:7 the God of our Lord Jesus. 1 Pet 1:3 Heb 1:8-9 God anointed Jesus.

> I am ascending to my Father and your Father, to my God and your God. John 20:17

**Even ascended, Jesus still has the same God** of him and of us Rev 1:1, 1:6, 3:12

We could say of Joseph and Jesus that they were essentially equal to their master in many ways - but certainly *not in all things*. They are never equal as King or ultimate ruler because their authority is *given to them*. the one giving is always over the one receiving.

> Therefore let all the house of Israel know assuredly that God has made Him both Lord and Christ--this Jesus whom you crucified."  Acts 2:36

Meaning he wasn't always. See the echo of Pharaoh's command, "See, I have placed you over all the land of Egypt"

Comment: You had 3 negative votes here and not one of those voters had the wherewithal, or should I say "guts" to tell you why they voted you down. That should be very telling. Maybe deep, deep down, they know that they may indeed be on the wrong track, otherwise, why would they withhold their reasoning. My vote up should at least put you positive. Keep up the good work.....

Comment: @OldeEnglish hmmm, any Q that touches a nerve gets promptly closed to avoid hearing the 'music', thx. According to RL above, Jesus isn't God anyway...

Comment: @RevelationLad, by that logic/theology, Jesus is sitting/standing next to himself!? And wow, you've thrown in a few texts, then made the rest up of pure opinion - 3 seats? The HS is never anywhere to be seen.

Comment: @Revelation Lad- First of all, Heb, 1:8 is a typical gross miss-translation of the original language, translated by Trinity biased minds. 2) In John 8:40, Jesus is speaking separately of the (Almighty) God, as in Him being a separate spiritual person. 3) In John 8:58, Jesus says that he was in existence before Abraham, which is true but not as God, but as the Word of God and don't get me going on John 1:1. The translators of the modern day bibles were the obfuscationists and you and the likes of you, fell "hook line and sinker" for their mistruths. And that is the sad truth of the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Father is God, the Son is God and the Spirit is God.

The Spirit is called God.

> “Ananias,” Peter asked, “why has Satan filled your heart to lie to the Holy Spirit and to keep back part of the proceeds of the land? While it remained unsold, did it not remain your own? **And after it was sold, were not the proceeds at your disposal? How is it that you have contrived this deed in your heart? You did not lie to us but to God!”**
> Acts 5:3‭-‬4 NRSV-CI
> https://bible.com/bible/2015/act.5.3-4.NRSV-CI

So is the Son.

> No one has ever seen God. **It is God the only Son, who is close to the Father's heart, who has made him known.**
> John 1:18 NRSV-CI
> https://bible.com/bible/2015/jhn.1.18.NRSV-CI

So this doesn't disprove the Trinity in the slightest.

Comment: Do the verses you cited  say that  God  is a trinity?

Answer (score -3):

Jesus has seen God and declared the Father:

> No one has seen God at any time. The only begotten Son, who is in the bosom of the Father, He has declared *Him*. (John 1:18) [NKJV]

This demonstrates when speaking of God, the Son, and the Father each is distinct from the other. When used without specifying a member of the Trinity "God" means the Father, and the Son, and the Holy Spirit collectively. Therefore, when the Son declares the Father, He necessarily also declares Himself. He does not declares Himself or the Father as "God" as the term used as such means all three, not one individual.

A picture of God's throne also demonstrates this reality:

> All things that the Father has are Mine. Therefore I said that He will take of Mine and declare *it* to you. (John 16:15)

If Father has a throne it is the Son's. Unless we are to believe the Father is left to stand when the Son is seated, the throne of "God" must be composed of more than one place to sit. Just as Father and Son must be included in the term God, the Father's throne and the Son's throne collectively make up God's throne:

> Therefore being exalted to the right hand of God, and having received from the Father the promise of the Holy Spirit, He poured out this which you now see and hear. (Acts 2:33)

As in John's Prologue, there is a distinction between God, Father, and Son, and in this case, the Holy Spirit. The only correct way to **individually** describe the Son is at the right hand of God.

Comment: As a parallel, the LORD God put both David and Solomon on His (God’s) throne. “Then Solomon sat on the throne of the LORD as king in place of David his father” (1 Chron. 29:23). But neither David nor Solomon were God just because they were granted by God to rule as God’s representatives on God’s throne. As God’s chosen, anointed kings, David and Solomon were granted to sit on God’s throne. So is the risen Jesus Christ.

Comment: I hardly recognized your answer, after your edit. Could you possibly have gotten yourself anymore entangled. Talk about OBFUSCATION. I see that you removed your obfuscation comment by the way. At least that is something. After Acts 2:33, we have 2:34,35 "..."JEHOVAH" said to my lord: "Sit at My right hand, until I place your enemies as a stool for your feet" (NWT). As for the holy spirit, in 2:33 (the "hs" is not capitalized), it (the "hs") is POURED out and therefore INFUSED into those present at Pentecost. There is no 3rd spiritual personage being talked about here. Nice one Alex B.

Comment: It was me and not Alex that down voted you, by the way.

Comment: Some insist that the God of the bible is triune even though the doctrine is not in the bible and remove God's name even though it originally appeared almost 7000 times. More than any other names.

Comment: @OldeEnglish. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexBalilo You mention Solomon and David. The context is Solomon sitting because David is absent. What happens when both are present? If there is one throne, one is seated and one is not. So when God's throne is described a having **two** places to sit, which is clear from the Scripture you cite, both can be seated. When both are seated, why does the Scripture say at the right hand of **God** and not the right hand of the the **Father**? You conflate what is separate: God and Father. Your reasoning is your doctrine which says God=Father, despite Scripture which treats them as separate.