# Does Luke 23:46 indicate that Jesus believed his God was the source of his life?

Tags: john, luke, ecclesiastes

Luke 23:46 ASV

> And Jesus, crying with a loud voice, said, Father, into thy hands I commend my spirit: and having said this, he gave up the ghost.

Jesus also said in John 6:56 ASV that,

> As the living Father sent me, and I live because of the Father; so he that eateth me, he also shall live because of me.

Do these statements of Jesus indicate he believed his God was the source of his life?

Ecclesiastes 12:7 ASV says

> and the dust returneth to the earth as it was, and the spirit returneth unto God who gave it.

Comment: @Rajesh Where is your question?

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47522/why-does-jesus-commit-his-spirit-into-his-fathers-hands-at-death?rq=1 looks very similar.

Comment: @Steve That is similar, but this question asks about word meaning.

Comment: @Rajesh this is the closest I could find but quite different: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/72985/is-there-another-explanation-for-the-contradiction-on-luke-2343-john-2017-i/73006#73006

Comment: @Steve If you disagree, should I move my answer there?

Comment: No problem leaving it here - the only close vote if for 'opinion' which seems odd to me.

Comment: @Dottard. The questions are similar but the other does not ask whether the statements of Jesus indicate that he believed his God was the source of his life.

Comment: We wouldn't even need this verse to know that Jesus would see the Father as his source of life, no matter who or what he is - uniformly throughout the scriptures God is repeatedly proclaimed as the source of *all* life (Dt 32:39, Job 33:4, Acts 17:25, Neh 9:6, 1 Tim 6:13). Even just calling him 'Father' implies this plainly. Voted to close as this question isn't really asking anything meaningfully different about the source passage from the duplicate, and feels more like a thinly veiled doctrinal question.

Comment: @Steve Taylor. And Rajesh question about Stephen entrusting his spirit to Jesus is not?

Comment: @AlexBalilo - thanks for highlighting. The last line of his question was clearly veering into doctrinal territory, but at least the rest clearly arises from the text, whereas this feels like more of a shoe-horned attempt of a theological issue into a passage that doesn't touch on it. I've edited Rajesh's question to bring it more on-topic, but the premise of this one is more awkward and difficult to think of a way to substantiate.

Comment: @SteveTaylor. If you pay equal attention to all questions on this site, you will realize that a lot of them are doctrinal.

Comment: @SteveTaylor. Clearly arising from the text, really? How about Jesus plain statement over deduction and circular reasoning?How about a doctrine that is not in the bible?

Answer (score 5):

The best insight for the meaning of the word παρατίθημι, translated "commend," is the Hebrew words it translates in the Septuagint (LXX).  The root meaning of the word means *to place beside*.  The Hebrew words mean *to set, hand over, lay or set in [his] presence, leave behind, set towards*.  The picture is *leaving something with someone to guard or take care of it while gone*.  Thus, "Father, I place my spirit in your hands" with the idea of safe keeping.  Also, apparently Jesus quoted Psalm 31:5.

```
         Into your hand I commit [אַפְקִ֪יד] my spirit; 
  you have redeemed me, O LORD, faithful God. (ESV)
```

> εἰς χεῖράς σου παραθήσομαι τὸ πνεῦμά μου, ἐλυτρώσω με, κύριε ὁ θεὸς τῆς ἀληθείας.
> (Psalm 30:6, LXX)

**Figure 1**. Hebrew words  translates in the LXX. (generated with Logos Bible Software)

[image]

Comment: Where did you get that graph?

Comment: @Omar See edit.

Answer (score 1):

The first scripture the OP presented is in regard to Luke 33:46

> Father, into Your hands I commit My spirit.

Jesus had  been living under the law as man.  He never knew sin and therefore never knew death.  Knowing he was going to become a sin offering, and therefore death would ensue, he commits his spirit to the Father who will keep it safe, while he is dead for three days.

One hast to remember he has to go through the full process of living as a man under the law, fulfilling it and then actually die as a man.

This particular scripture does not show that God is his source of  life, But only the Father would keep his spirit for safekeeping.

The second scripture the OP asked is; John 6:57

> As the living Father sent Me and I live because of the Father, so also the one feeding on Me, he also will live because of Me.

> ( The one eating this bread will live to the age.”)

Jesus was living on total dependence on the life of the Father's Spirit while here on earth. The Father  was his source of life and those who feed on Jesus, (believe in him) have that same life in them.  They have the life from Father through Jesus who was given for life.

This verse does show that God is the source of life in Jesus here.  He lived because of the Father.